# Is it possible to use CCSpriteBatchNode with single file images

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

Is it possible to use CCSpriteBatchNode with an animation that uses single image files. This is the animation that I am creating:

```
CCAnimation *begFlamesAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFiles:@"begFlames_" frameCount:54 delay:0.03f];
```

Is this possible or does CCSpriteBatchNode only work with spriteSheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CCSpriteBatchNode and the CCSprite children it contains must use the same texture. If you use individual images, you create individual textures for each image. Then you can't spritebatch, and it's wasting memory compared to a texture atlas containing all these images.